# Can't set cookie in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cookies, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 to develop my application. But I have some problem about setting cookie. Here is some code in `app/routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    // Set a cookie before a response has been created ??
    Cookie::queue('test0', '123', 10);

    $app = App::getFacadeApplication();
    $version = $app::VERSION;

    //Creating Custom Responses
    $response = Response::make("<html><body>
        Version: $version <br/>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            document.write(document.cookie);
        </script>
        </body></html>", 200);

    $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('test1', '0123', 10));

    //Queue after response created
    Cookie::queue('test2', '123', 10);
    Cookie::queue('test3', '123', 10);
    setcookie('test4', '123', time() + 60*10);

    return $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('test5', '0123', 10));
});
```

But when I run this code, it doesn't set all value. Here is my result:
[image: result]

Only the php build-in function work,
any other function like `Cookie::queue`, `withCookie` didn't work for me, but in the `Cookies set by this page` popup like the image above, it still have all cookie value
So, what is the problem here? 
And why the value of `test2` is not `'123'` ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the cookie you set is [HttpOnly cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie).

> HttpOnly cookies can only be used when transmitted via HTTP (or
>   HTTPS). They are not accessible through non-HTTP APIs such as
>   JavaScript. This restriction mitigates, but does not eliminate, the
>   threat of session cookie theft via cross-site scripting (XSS).
>   HttpOnly cookies are supported by most modern browsers.

`Cookie::make()` method takes seven parameters. You can set `httpOnly` (default is true) to false in laravel.

```
Cookie::make($name, $value, $minutes, $path, $domain, $secure, $httpOnly);
```

**Edit**

In laravel, cookie value is automatically encrypted with key which is set in `app/config/app.php` for security reason. To get what you want to do, you need to follow this two ways :

Just use traditional [setCookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) method in php.

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $host, $secure, $httpOnly);
```

Otherwise, you can use this tricky way. [Accessing unencrypted cookies](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3440)

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Great. It worked. But how do I get the real `test2` value, it still `eyJpdiI6IjlLR...`, not `123` ?